# How to disable dump symfony function on production

Tags: symfony

How to disable `dump()` function,
when its in production environment?
If i forget the dump function anywhere It crashes with an 500 error

Comment: Remove the `dump()` from your prod code, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: This is a recurring topic. The question is, why would you want to keep such call in your production code? The problem is in your code review.

Comment: You can just define an empty dump function in web/app.php.  It is annoying when you forget to remove the calls before checking in.

Comment: You would be better off setting up a pre-commit hook using some sort of linter to check for those, so it doesnt accidentally get pushed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should remove the `dump()`s from your production code, it doesn't have to be there.

But, [as noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006434/how-to-disable-dump-symfony-function-on-production#comment71189097_42006434) by [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad), since it can be annoying when you forget to remove them before checking in, you can define an empty `dump()` function at the begining of `web/app.php`:

<kbd>src\web\app.php</kbd>

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

function dump($object){
    return;
}


$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
//rest of app.php
```

Comment: Improving on this solution, instead of silently doing nothing and therefore inviting people to just forget dumps all over the plare, you should return a message: return "you forgot a dump in your code you dummy". I suggested and improvement to the answer but since I wasn't logged in it won't show up as me.

Comment: Returning a string can be problematic, it's better to just do nothing. Off-course, YMMV.

Comment: actually I meant to echo a string so that you get a visible sign that you messed up, but you could log the message or send an email etc... The point is that whereas downing the whole website with a 500 is overkill, leaving a dump in production should be problematic and strongly discouraged in some way or another, but this method rather encourages devs to just blindly leave dumps lying around all over the place.

Comment: +1 for logging usages of dump. a) Never show it to the public, b) be flexible about leaving it in the code making it transparent to the user, and c) Log it into a database or log file to allow you keep track of where it is used.

Comment: This is a nice solution and follows the null object pattern without "corrupting" the code.

Answer (score 3):

For **Symfony 4.1+**, you can modify `index.php` this way:

```
  if ($debug) {
     umask(0000);

     Debug::enable();
+ } else {
+     \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::setHandler(function($var) {});
+ }
```

Then `dump()` will do nothing when called. If you want you can throw an Exception or write some log.

The problem is that the content of `dump()` will go to the web debug toolbar in dev mode, which can be easily overlooked. When deploying such code to production, user will then see an inline `dump()`!

Answer (score 1):

**NEW ANSWER AS OF 3.3:**

Now in **Symfony 3.3+**, *you can dump to prod environment*. Rather than turning up in the debug toolbar, it shows up in the content area of your page (so if you do this in the controller, it will be at the top).

This can be handy to debug things that don't do the same between dev and prod, and then you can leave your debug code in as you develop, but just make sure before you deploy to a production environment that you comment out any dumps.

Comment: but be careful: if you follow the optimization tips from  https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/performance.html, then the `dump`function is not available (I guess due to the `--no-dev`arg)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if the dump showed up in a log or as HTML comments so that it would be useful for those situations, where something in your production environment is not working quite right but you need to keep the production environment working as normal. Granted you can't output the pretty HTML you normally see in dump. I have used this technique before and it can be very useful for debugging production issues or some basic performance checks.