# Symfony2: only show twig dump() in dev

Tags: symfony, twig

Using twig dump() gives me this error in my prod environment:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: 
"Unknown "dump" function." at /home/.../all-pages.html.twig line 70
{"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Syntax(code: 0): 
Unknown \"dump\" function. at /home/.../all-pages.html.twig:70)"}
```

Now I thought being smart and put dump() inside an if statement:

```
{% if app.debug %} // also tried {% if app.environment == 'dev' %}

    {{ dump(joe) }}

{% endif }%
```

But this gives the same error in prod.

How can I use dump() in my dev environment and ignore it in prod?

Comment: You should remove dump statements before pushing to production.  However, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006434/how-to-disable-dump-symfony-function-on-production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior. **dump()** works in development environment because in the **AppKernel.php** file, there are :

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    // Some code ...
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
}
```

You can save this bundle for all environments by adding it in the **$bundles** array just above and **AppKernel.php**.

But be aware that this is not a good practice. You can also temporarily enable debug mode if necessary by changing this setting in **app.php** (false => true):

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Have good dev.